# Extracting Mean Parameter Estimates from Stan Output Table

Tags: stan

I understand how to extract chains from a Stan model but I was wondering if there was any quick way to extract the values displayed on the default Stan output table.

Here is some toy data

```
# simulate linear model
a <- 3 # intercept
b <- 2 # slope

# we can have both the predictor and the noise vary
x <- rnorm(28, 0, 1)
eps <- rnorm(28, 0, 2)
y <- a + b*x + eps
```

Which when we analyse

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x, df)
```

We can extract coefficients from

```
mod$coefficients

# (Intercept)           x 
#    3.355967    2.151597
```

I wondered if there is any way to do the equivalent with a Stan output table

```
# Step 1: Make List
data_reg <- list(N = 28, x = x, y = y)

# Step 2: Create Model String
write("
      data {
      int<lower=0> N;
      vector[N] x;
      vector[N] y;
      }
      parameters {
      real alpha;
      real beta;
      real<lower=0> sigma;
      }
      model {
      vector[N] mu;
      sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2);
      beta ~ normal(0,10);
      alpha ~ normal(0,100);
      for ( i in 1:N ) {
      mu[i] = alpha + beta * x[i];
      }
      y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
      }
      ", file = "temp.stan")


# Step 3: Generate MCMC Chains
fit1 <- stan(file = "temp.stan",    
             data = data_reg,        
             chains = 2,             
             warmup = 1000,          
             iter = 2000,            
             cores = 2,               
             refresh = 1000)
```

Now, when we call the model

```
fit1

# Output
#         mean se_mean   sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% n_eff Rhat
# alpha   3.33    0.01 0.40   2.57   3.06   3.33   3.59   4.13  1229    1
# beta    2.14    0.01 0.40   1.37   1.89   2.14   2.40   2.98  1470    1
# sigma   1.92    0.01 0.27   1.45   1.71   1.90   2.09   2.51  1211    1
# lp__  -31.92    0.05 1.30 -35.27 -32.50 -31.63 -30.96 -30.43   769    1
```

Is there any way to index and extract elements from the Output table displayed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want means, then the `get_posterior_mean` function will work. Otherwise, you assign the result of `print(fit1)` or `summary(print1)` to an object, you can extract stuff from that object, but it is probably better to just do `as.matrix(fit1)` or `as.data.frame(fit1)` and calculate whatever you want yourself on the resulting columns.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Goodrich. `get_posterior_means(fit1)` and `summary(fit1)$summary[,"means"]` worked great. I know generally it's much better to work with the chains themselves but I'm do data simulation trying to get Bayesian models to return estimates based on different coding schemes (treatment, deviation, simple, backwards difference etc.) and want to compare results with the parameters I use to create the data, raw means, and  results from NHST versions of the same models.